# Is it possible to be active in multiple windows at the same time in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I am trying to build a bot that I checks multiple sites at the same time and purchase an item when it comes in stock. I already made the script for the bot but I don't know how I can run it on multiple sites at once.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this:

### Spawn multiple Python instances

Simply run your code in multiple terminals.

- This would require minimal code modifications. However this is generally not a good approach, but it solves your problem.

### Use multi-threading

In simple terms, what threading does is to spawn a number of "threads" that runs the function `main()` at the same time. See below for a simple demo. What this does is to spawn 3 threads that "targets" the main function, and each of the main function visits python.org for 1000 seconds:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# your main monitoring program goes here
def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    time.sleep(1000)
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for _ in range(3):
        t = Thread(target=main, daemon=True)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

### Use multi-processing

- I believe multiprocessing can also solves the problem. But I did not write a similar snippet as in threading. The structure would be similar. I personally prefer multi-threading for these simple work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using multi-processing but I only got errors. I currently get the error "TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed" because I use "except NoSuchElementException:" in my code I tried to fix it but it cant find a solution